# Remove old glib after manually compiled a newer one

Tags: glib, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile `atk-2.18.0` from source for Debian Jessie but the `./configure` step fails with following messages:

```
*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.46.2, but GLIB (2.42.1)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
no
configure: error: 
*** GLIB 2.31.2 or better is required. The latest version of
*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/. If GLIB is installed
*** but not in the same location as pkg-config add the location of the file
*** glib-2.0.pc to the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH.
```

I have compiled `glib` myself as the version of `glib` in Debian Jessie repository is old and won't work for me. How do I remove the old version as suggested in the error message above?

Comment: Stop trying to do this.  Removing files from a distro-provided package is a great way to hose your system.  What you should be doing is the other stuff in that message to point atk at a different version of the library; you might want to look into jhbuild which will handle this stuff automatically…

Comment: Ok! I changed my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the path of newly compiled `glib` and it's working now.